# Make libxml tag a synonym for libxml2 on StackOverflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

Libxml has been v2 seemingly forever, no doubt some v1 installations are out there, but the libxml tag is used synonymously for libxml2 on StackOverflow.

*Update* this is still outstanding - anyone else like to support this proposal?  At the moment libxml has 123 instances and libxml2 296.

*Update 2* a year has passed - still no synonym.

*Update 3* another 6 months more have passed - now 196 v 477 instances ...

Comment: Instead of submitting a new request I bump this one. It's hard to search questions regarding this library and we get duplicate questions. Please help :)

Comment: Unless compelling objections arise, I'm going to do this in the next 24 hours. Not sure how this didn't get much attention (really, only 79 views since June 2011?) - thanks for following up on it.

Comment: @Tim - sounds good, thanks!

Comment: @Tim - March 2013 - still no synonym ...

Comment: @TimPost - How is it going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no harm in seeing how it works out. Synonym created.